# poseEigenToMsg is not a member of 'tf'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use tf::poseEigenToMsg from this package:

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8h.html

But it doesn't appear to be a member of the namespace tf... I'm assuming this is an issue with either my cmake file, or a package.xml... but I'm not even entirely sure what to specify in each. I'm including tf_conversions in my cmake file, as eigen_conversions didn't work.

Any help getting this to work would be much appreciated!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271498/poseeigentomsg-is-not-a-member-of-%27tf%27/) by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-26**:
I'm pretty sure that function should be there, so make sure the error is not actually something along the lines of "no candidate for your exact input arguments".

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-26**:
Also: as always with these kind of errors: please include some snippets of code that show what you are doing exactly. Without that this is going to be difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks very much for the help everyone, I was not including the correct header. For anyone reading this in the future, It's

```
#include <eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h>
```

---

Originally posted by [jbeck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/28876/jbeck28/) with karma: 101 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you include the correct header from the package?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-09-27**:
This error message usually means that you don't have the header in your `#include` directives.